# Regex "inter" text

Tags: java, regex

I am trying create a properly regex to validate some values, I will explain next:

I have to validate this lines with he :

```
$_globalVariables/ns:GlobalVariables/VARIABLENAME/ESB/System
$_globalVariables/ns:GlobalVariables/VARIABLENAME2/ESB/System
$_globalVariables/ns:GlobalVariables/VARIABLENAME3/ESB/System
```

With this line:

```
$_globalVariables/ns:GlobalVariables/[varname]/ESB/Sistema
```

I tried some combinations, and read about regex, but I am "newbie" in this topic and I cant get the correct result.

I think that is some like this:

```
\$_globalVariables/ns:GlobalVariables/(.*?)/ESB/System
```

- `\$_globalVariables/ns:GlobalVariables/` -> Text to validate in the start
- `(.*?)` -> Anything
- `/ESB/System` -> End of the math text

Sorry my english, if somebody need more info, please ask me.

Comment: Please don't update you question such that it invalidates people's answers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape the `$` character, as it's a reserved character meaning end of line/input according to context.

Here's how:

```
String[] input = {
            "$_globalVariables/ns:GlobalVariables/VARIABLENAME/ESB/System",
            "$_globalVariables/ns:GlobalVariables/VARIABLENAME2/ESB/System",
            "$_globalVariables/ns:GlobalVariables/VARIABLENAME3/ESB/System" };
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\$_globalVariables/ns:GlobalVariables/(.+?)/ESB/System");
for (String s: input) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Found: " + m.group());
        System.out.println("\t with variable name: " + m.group(1));
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Found: $_globalVariables/ns:GlobalVariables/VARIABLENAME/ESB/System
 with variable name: VARIABLENAME
Found: $_globalVariables/ns:GlobalVariables/VARIABLENAME2/ESB/System
     with variable name: VARIABLENAME2
Found: $_globalVariables/ns:GlobalVariables/VARIABLENAME3/ESB/System
     with variable name: VARIABLENAME3
```

**Notes**

- `$` is double-escaped in the `Pattern` --> `\\$`
- Using **1+** reluctant quantifier instead of **0+** reluctant quantifier for group 1: we assume at least one character in the variable name, right?
- Java `Pattern` page API [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg)

Comment: @OGHaza uugh. Thanks! Although it looks like my answer is still kind of valid I guess... (note: changed answer to reflect group capture)

Comment: I see your answer, but I added the scape before :) Anyway, the most difficult to me was the "(.+?)" :) Thanks, I mark now the answer.

If possible generalice the [name] when the string contains a [text]? (The rest of the string can change)

Comment: @user1422434 you're welcome! Not sure I understand your additional question about generalisation... If you can be more specific I'll try and update my answer.

Comment: Sorry, its more problematic that I think in my mind :) Thanks for the response and your help!